# Bootstrap card overlay with elements on center and bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have created a card with a background image,
I have used the basic [example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/card/#image-overlays) from bootstrap docs but inside the overlay I have to align the elements in a column on center except the last one that must aligned on the bottom.

This is what I've [created so far](https://jsfiddle.net/a4tr3ydn/5/) but to me the html looks quite clunky. Is there a better way to achieve the same result? Like with less divs or classes?

```
<div class="page-wrapper">
   <div class="card bg-dark text-white">
      <img class="card-img" src="https://placeimg.com/1000/450/nature" alt="Card image">
      <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex flex-column">
         <div class="content-wrapper container d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
            <p class="card-text">Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
            <h1 class="card-title">Card title</h1>
            <p class="card-text">This content is a little bit longer.</p>            
         </div>

         <ul class="nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#detail">Detail</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#gallery">Gallery</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a diagram of the desired result? I'm a bit unclear on the final objective.

Comment: The final result is the one shown on jsfiddle. The final objective is optimize all the classes applied on the HTML. I'm new on flexbox and I would know if there is a better way to optain the same result.

Comment: Are you looking to reduce the number of CSS classes that you're using? If so, why?

Comment: As I have written above I think that that HTMl code is clunky, I was asking if there is a better way to avoind flex inside flex or lot of divs. Why? Optimization, Readability, Code quality.

Comment: I think you're trying to fix something that's not broken. But rather applying subjective taste and style. The code is definitely readable and of quality. Not everything has to be as few elements and CSS classes as possible. If you want to reduce something like this: `class="content-wrapper container d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center"` you could create a scoping class and selector along the lines of `.alpha .content-wrapper` and override/add the flex properties that way instead of all the classes.